# A reverse sentence structure?

Tags: grammar, syntax

So I have been watching this Japanese TV Series called ***Mare*** and I've been wondering most of the time on their sentence structures. It's something like this:

> しょうがないですね？ とるーさんは。

Can someone explain the structure above? ^~^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something that you will commonly find in colloquial spoken Japanese, but it is rarely found in written Japanese.  The major exception to this is, of course, when an author is writing dialogue between two or more individuals.

Here's what's happening,  the speaker says:

> しょうがないですね？

Then, realizing that the topic of the sentence is unclear, the speaker adds on:

> とるーさんは。

This happens because Japanese is a highly contextual language, so if the context is clear, the supporting details are frequently left off.  In real time conversation, the speaker occasionally assumes too much about the mutually understood context, and adds it on after the fact in the manner you see here.

Sometimes you see this to add emphasis in spoken colloquial conversations, but it is *highly* unlikely (I'm willing to even say probability < 0.01%) that you will find this method of emphasis in formal, written Japanese.